# E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket﹕ IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory

Tags: android, exception, server

I am getting following error in my app only sometimes while playing or pausing audio coming from server and error is coming not at a particular point.Is it the programming error or error from data coming from server and what does this error mean?

```
E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket﹕ IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are u writing file to device and fetching it later on???

Comment: @Developer I am running my project on device by connecting it through cable to my laptop..